# проблема при установки шаблона на Joomla 3x

Tags: php, веб-программирование, joomla

[image]

вот это сообщение выходит при любых шаблонах установленных:

Comment: $modCnt = count($mods);   // это 215 line

Comment: $max  = count($activeMod); // это 288 line

Comment: Нужно более конкретно описывать проблему и процесс установки. Также нужно указывать конкретную версию Джумлы и название, версию и источник шаблона.